# Water flowing across an inclined plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow

There is a blue plate between the two black plates and the water flows between the plates in the direction of the red arrow. Is the flow velocity greater at the top of the blue plate or at the bottom? Why?

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you want to say “no gravity” to eliminate a variable? I took it to be up/down in the way shown on page. Just asking. Especially if we think it probably won’t matter but are only *almost* certain of that

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  What are your thoughts on this (assuming it is an inviscid flow)?

Comment: @ChetMiller The top surface should have high speed and the bottom surface should have low speed.

Comment: I found [a simulation](https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/fluids/) which can be used for experimenting with this and similar setups. It allows to plot the local velocity, so it can be used for finding an answer to your question for a certain angle of inclination of the plate and initial flow velocity. However, judging from that simulation, these parameters have a great impact on the behaviour on the system (in particular whether the flow is laminar or turbulent), so I doubt there is a general answer.